# Post a file to a .php page from Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

On my website I have a .php script to which our customers can post orders.

```
  $destname = CreateUniqueOrderFileName();
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destname))         
      echo "OK";
    else 
      echo "ERROR: move";                  
  }
```

So for my clients I wrote an app in C# and if I upload an order I do something like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
byte[] response = client.UploadFile("http://mywebsite/order.php", "POST", orderFile);
```

But now I have a customer who uses Oracle and wants to post an order using PL/SQL. 
I try to tell him he has to do a file uploaded via HTTP POST and use multipart/form-data but he does not understand me. Maybe I'm using the wrong vocabulary or not using standards.

So does someone have an example of how to post a file to a .php script in PL/SQL or a suggestion where to find more information uploading a file to a .php webpage with an Oracle client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could find a way to do a POST request using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC2388. So I changed the .php script to something like this.

```
   $fp = fopen('php://input','r');
   $content = stream_get_contents($fp);
   $destname = CreateUniqueOrderFileName();
   $isWritten = @file_put_contents($destname, $content); 
   if($isWritten===false)
   {
     echo "ERROR: could not write file: ".$destname;    
     return;                
   }
```

Using this we where able to post the order using the UTL_HTTP lib to do a HTTP POST.

Comment: Downvoting since this does not answer the original question (file uploaded from Oracle using PL/SQL via HTTP POST using multipart/form-data content type).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use PL/SQL package UTL_HTTP to do a HTTP POST

http://awads.net/wp/2005/11/30/http-post-from-inside-oracle/

Another option might be to use a Java Stored Procedure

Comment: Yeah, but the multipart/form-data encoding has to be performed by the user code.